# Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey with FormBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-form-builder

The following minimally reproducible dummy code throws this error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Restarted application in 987ms.
I/flutter (10106): Key: [LabeledGlobalKey<FormBuilderState>#070c0 GlobalFormKey #SignIn ]

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.

The key [LabeledGlobalKey<FormBuilderState>#070c0 GlobalFormKey #SignIn ] was used by multiple widgets. The parents of those widgets were:
- FormBuilderWrapper-[LabeledGlobalKey<FormBuilderState>#070c0 GlobalFormKey #SignIn ]
- _BodyBuilder
A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.
```

Dummy Code:

```
class SignInScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> key =
      GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>(debugLabel: 'GlobalFormKey #SignIn ');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Dummy")),
      body: FormBuilderWrapper(
        key: key,
        childrenInColumn: [
          FormBuilderEmail(),
          FormBuilderPassword(identifierForField: "password")
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

```
class FormBuilderWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> childrenInColumn;
  final Key key;
  const FormBuilderWrapper({
    @required this.key,
    @required this.childrenInColumn,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Key: $key");
    return FormBuilder(
      key: key,
      child: Column(
        children: this.childrenInColumn,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';

class FormBuilderEmail extends StatelessWidget {
  const FormBuilderEmail({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FormBuilderTextField(
      name: "email",
    );
  }
}
class FormBuilderPassword extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final String identifierForField;

  const FormBuilderPassword({
    @required this.identifierForField,
    this.hintText = "Password",
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FormBuilderTextField(
      name: identifierForField,
    );
  }
}
```

---

What I don't understand is that only 1 widget uses the Key and that's the `FormBuilder` widget(I didn't count 'FormBuilderWrapper' as it merely passes the key to `FormBuilder`)

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this is happening? An explanation of which are the "multiple widgets" using the same `GlobalKey` would be great

Comment: I get this all the time during debug. Never in release mode or in a published app. Don't really know why.

Comment: try renaming the 'key' parameter of FormBuilderWrapper

Comment: Yup, I realized that myself too just now! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it why you were getting the error. It was because of this statement. It is recognizing variable name key as keyword key.

```
 final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> key =
      GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>(debugLabel: 'GlobalFormKey #SignIn ');
```

Below is the modified version of the dummy code you uploaded. I didn't get any errors after execution but please check at your end.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';
    
    class SignInScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> _formkey =
      GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>(debugLabel: 'GlobalFormKey #SignIn ');

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Dummy")),
          body: FormBuilderWrapper(
            fomrkey: _formkey,
            childrenInColumn: [
              FormBuilderEmail(),
              FormBuilderPassword(identifierForField: "password")
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class FormBuilderWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
      final List<Widget> childrenInColumn;
      final Key fomrkey;
      const FormBuilderWrapper({
        required this.fomrkey,
        required this.childrenInColumn,
      });
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        print("Key: $fomrkey");
        return FormBuilder(
          key: fomrkey,
          child: Column(
            children: this.childrenInColumn,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class FormBuilderEmail extends StatelessWidget {
      const FormBuilderEmail({
        Key? fomrkey1,
      }) : super(key: fomrkey1);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FormBuilderTextField(
          name: "email",
        );
      }
    }
    
    class FormBuilderPassword extends StatelessWidget {
      final String hintText;
      final String identifierForField;
    
      const FormBuilderPassword({
        required this.identifierForField,
        this.hintText = "Password",
      });
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FormBuilderTextField(
          name: identifierForField,
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

They are using the same key because when you create the `FormBuilderWrapper` you pass the key to it, and then inside you return a formBuilder passing the same key you gave the `FormBuilderWrapper`.

for what i understand, it does not matter that the key just "passes by" and goes to the `FormBuilder`, because `FormBuilderWrapper` is still being created with that key.

Answer (score 0):

I received this same error in a form and it was quiet hard to debug where it was coming from.

I had a scaffold which redirected to an `addItem` scaffold in a new screen. There I had a scaffold with the form and a `GlobalKey` to work with the form.

This was the code I was using to save my item:

```dart
  void _saveNewItem() {
    if (_formKey.currentState != null) {
      _formKey.currentState!.save();
      final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
      if (!isValid) {
        return;
      }
      if (_editItem.id == 0) {
        _editItem.copyWith(
          id: (DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch / 10000).round(),
        );
        Provider.of<MyProvider>(context, listen: false).add(_editItem);
      } else {
        print('TODO: Save edit item');
      }
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }
  }
```

My mistake was creating an item that I did not pass to to my provider, instead I just had too change it to:

```dart
  void _saveNewItem() {
    if (_formKey.currentState != null) {
      _formKey.currentState!.save();
      final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
      if (!isValid) {
        return;
      }
      if (_editItem.id == 0) {
        var addItem = _editItem.copyWith(
          id: (DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch / 10000).round(),
        );
        Provider.of<MyProvider>(context, listen: false).add(addItem );
      } else {
        print('TODO: Save edit item');
      }
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }
  }
```

This does not seem to be related but the error of the question was then triggered and this solved the issue crashing with that `Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.` after saving the form the second time.